# Proving $\frac2\pi\cos^{-1}\left(-\sqrt{\frac12\rho}+\sqrt{\frac12(1-\rho)}\right)-\frac12= \frac2\pi\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\rho}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that the following real-valued functions
>
> $$A = \frac{2}{\pi} ~\cos^{-1} \left(-~\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}~\rho}~ + ~\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}~(1-\rho})\right)-\frac{1}{2}$$
>
> $$B = \frac{2}{\pi} ~\sin^{-1} (\sqrt{\rho})$$
>
> are equal for all $0 \leq \rho \leq 1$

This is easily established empirically, but I'm stuck at first base proving it mathematically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to let $\rho = \sin^2\theta$, which makes the statement equivalent to proving $A=B$ for all $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

$$B = \frac{2}{\pi}\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}) = \frac{2}{\pi}\theta$$

$$A = \frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\theta\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \sin\theta\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ = \frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\theta\cdot\cos \frac{\pi}{4} - \sin\theta\cdot\sin \frac{\pi}{4}\right) -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ = \frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) -\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\theta + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\theta$$

Thus $A=B$. All of the manipulations between trig and inverse trig functions are well-defined with no multiples of $\pi$ needed because our angles were always between $0$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, within the range of $\cos^{-1}(x)$

Comment: Wow. This is how I started working on it.  Looking back at my hand-scratched notes, I was never close. Thanks so much.

Comment: This seemed clear to me last month.  Now I can't see how you get $+\frac{1}{2}$ at the end.  I see $\frac{pi}{4}$.  What am I missing?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{4}\times \frac{2}{\pi} = ?$ Upvote my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: I'm not permitted to do so because I'm new to the forum.  Thanks much though!

Comment: @ChuckSmith You should be able to accept answers

Comment: I don't know how.  I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

hint: take cosine of $\frac{π}{2}B$ and use double angle formulae on $cos(\frac{π}{2}A+\frac{π}{4})$. Then you can deduce $cos(\frac{π}{2}A)=cos(\frac{π}{2}B)$. Since you already have the result empirically this should be proof enough. (You can probably prove that it is the 1st solution to this equation, rather than $\frac{π}{2}A=\frac{π}{2}B+2πk)$.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.